# Partial derivatives of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f:\mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=e^{x_1x_3} \int_0^{x_2}e^{s^2}ds$ where $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3).$ Find the partials $\partial x_1,\partial x_2, \partial x_3.$

I assume I have to use FTC, but I'm not sure how to approach this in $\mathbb{R}^3.$ Also since the integral is from $0$ to $x^2$ does that imply that $x_2>x_3$ or how to interpret this? Any hints? I'm not familiar with multivariable integrals...

Comment: Why in $\;\Bbb R^3\;$ ? You have an integral of a function of one variable, exactly as in calculus I...and exactly as simple as that. After that, you have partial derivatives of a function with two variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\;F\;$ be a primitive function of $\;e^{x^2}\;$ (why does this primivte exist?) , then

$$\int_0^{x_2} e^{s^2} ds=F(x_2)-F(0)\implies f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=e^{x_1}e^{x_3}\int_0^{x_2}e^{s^2}=e^{x_1}e^{x_3}(F(x_2)-F(0))\implies$$

$$f_{x_1}'=f_{x_3}'=e^{x_1}e^{x_3}(F(x_2)-F(0))\;,\;\;f_{x_2}'=e^{x_1}e^{x_3}F'(x_2)=e^{x_1}e^{x_2}e^{x_3^2}$$